# How to add customData to 'Name' attribute in plotly.js?

Tags: plotly.js

I am using Plotly to show a duration of an event with start Time, end Time and duration details on the tooltip.
I am adding type= scatter and adding 4 markers at the corner of every rectangle. I'm storing all data like - Start Time, End Time , Duration as customData[0] ,customData[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qY6KN.png) ,customData[2] respectively.
The data appears fine on the hover template but I want to show the same data for the name because the user should see the tooltip throughout the entire area and not just at the corners where markers are present.

However,  text: '%{customdata[0]}', nor   name:'%{customdata[0]}', is working.

Any suggestions?

```
const graphData = {
    x: DataX,
    y: DataY,
      xaxis: 'x',
      yaxis: 'y3',
      mode:"markers",
      fill: "toself",
      customdata: ['StartTime','endTime','duration'],  // N*3 Array
      fillcolor: "rgb(0, 0, 0,)",
      opacity:.6,
      marker: {sizeref: 4000, sizemode: "area",size:.05, color:'#000000', opacity:1 },
      hoverinfo: "<br>Start Date: %{customdata[0]}<br> Duration : %{customdata[2]} <br> End Date : %{customdata[1]}",
      legendgroup: "rgb(0, 0, 0)",
      hovertemplate :"<br>Start Date: %{customdata[0]}<br> Duration : %{customdata[2]} <br> End Date : %{customdata[1]} ",
      text: '%{customdata[0]}',
     // hoverinfo:'text',
      name:'%{customdata[0]}',
      type: "scatter",
    };
```

[image: Unable to load customdata values in tooltip]